# CQ5 column control generated html

Tags: aem

We are working on a project where we need a decent level of control in CSS to implement the design but have been told by the dev team that the generated html is:

```
<div class="parsys_column cq-colctrl-lt1"> <!-- "cq-colctrl-lt1" defines width of child divs (33%) -->
    <div class="parsys_column cq-colctrl-lt1-c0"><!--another components go here --></div>
    <div class="parsys_column cq-colctrl-lt1-c1"><!--another components go here --></div>
    <div class="parsys_column cq-colctrl-lt1-c2"><!--another components go here --></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Looking into column controls I see you can [change the `cq-colctrl-` class](http://www.sixdimensions.com/creating-a-column-control-in-adobe-cq/) but I can't find answers to the following:

1, Can the clear both div (generated by CQ) be removed or only shown in author mode?

2, Can the column control be added within a component?

3, Can the column class be set per component or is it a global setting?

4, Can you control the styles of the column classes and override the generated CQ5 CSS (eg for a responsive site?)?

Comment: Do you mean out of the box? Or do you mean can someone overlay the default Columns component to do those things? I'd say they're all technically feasible, depending on how much time you have.

Comment: Yeah, I mean by adapting the out of the box code.

Comment: I was considering 'adaptation' and OOTB as opposites :) It's really something that you'd need to discuss with your developers — all mark-up generated by CQ can be turned off if needed, or some can be adapted slightly, but the level of adaptation depends on your specific use case & the effort involved depends on your team and your deadline.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less the response I got back from them in the end, cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want embed column component in your component:

1. go crxdelite in the /apps/geometrixx-outdoors/components/colctrl

just create package via site admin and specify the above path and download package then you can see, how column component is created.
http://jenikya.com/blog/2013/01/editing-column-widths-in-cq5.html
but it's better look at that path is more clear.